# Problem creating new account using docusign API

Tags: api, new-operator, docusignapi, account

When I try to create a new account using the API I am getting this error:

```
{ "error": "internal_server_error", "error_description": "No site id
was found for region: None", "reference_id":
"e2ff6d67-119e-4b04-9325-512047e5baf5" }
```

My payload is:

```
{  "accounts": [  {
        "address": {
        "street_address": "santendar",
        "locality": "santendar",
        "region": "spanish area",
        "country": "ESP",
        "postal_code": "34567",
        "phone": "12345"
      },
       "admin_user": {
        "email_address": "abhistar002@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "team",
        "job_title": "somejob"
      },
      "name": "testAccount",
      "plan_id": "**********************",
      "website": "example.com",
      "reseller_id": "***********",
      "customer_id": "************",
      "paid_seats": "2"
    }   ] }
```

Which worked before. I have created many accounts using this API structure.

Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you making the request? What is the URL and header info? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

IF you look at this https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/Accounts/create you'll see that the Address part of your call is a bit different and should look like this:

```
 "address": {
      "street1": "sample string 1",
      "street2": "sample string 2",
      "city": "sample string 3",
      "state": "sample string 4",
      "zip": "sample string 5",
      "phone": "sample string 6",
      "fax": "sample string 7",
      "country": "sample string 8"
    }
```